# PDE for heat conduction with loss

Tags: partial-derivative, heat-equation

Consider the following PDE:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}u = \alpha^2 \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}u -bu, \ \ b>0, 0<x<L$$

The problem asks to "set the time derivative in the PDE to zero, solve for the steady state solution".

By separation of variables, let $u(t,x)=T(t)X(x)$ and plug in PDE. We get

$$0 = \alpha^2 T \frac{d^2 X }{d x^2}u-bTX \Longrightarrow \frac{d^2 X }{d x^2}-\frac{b}{\alpha^2}X=0$$

We get $$X(x) = A\sin\left(\sqrt{-\frac{b}{\alpha^2}}x\right)+B\cos\left(\sqrt{-\frac{b}{\alpha^2}}x\right)$$

I am a bit confused about the answer I get here since it is a complex number. But the answer should be

$$u(t,x) = e^{-bt} u_0(t,x)$$ where $u_0(t,x)$ solves the heat conduction in a rod (without loss). I am not sure where I made error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2(f(x))%2Fdx%5E2%20-%20b*f(x)%20%3D%200) to the differential equation is sum of exponential functions.

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2} - b^2f(t) = 0$$

$$f(x) = k_1 \exp(-bt) +k_2 \exp(bt)$$

If you had opposite sign of $bTX$ then it would be complex conjugate roots and sine-cosine linear combination:

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2} + b^2f(t) = 0$$

giving

$$f(x) = k_1 \sin(bt) +k_2 \cos(bt)$$